# Can I use createReadStream() from fs with a base64 image instead of a path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am using the **createReadStream()** function from fs of Node in order to save an Image after... anyway my question is:

Is it necessary to pass a path as an argument to the function ? Can I pass the image in base64 encoded format or other encoding without first saving it in the filesystem and using its path?

Current:

```
const readStream = createReadStream('my_route');
```

Want to:

```
const readStream = createReadStream(my_image);
```

The final purpose is to save the image by the **GridFS** system:

```
Attachment = mongoose_gridfs.createModel() // The GridFS object

const readStream = createReadStream('my_route');

const options = { filename: 'sample.txt', contentType: 'text/plain' };

this.Attachment.write(options, readStream, (error, file) => {
   console.log('File saved!');
});
```

Comment: You don't need to save to a file just to read it again. If you got the image as a stream then you can `pipe` it. What is the image source?

Comment: The image is being retrieved in base64 by the frontend call, my question is how can I use the createReadStream() function with this instead of a path parameter

Comment: You cannot use `createReadStream` without a path parameter. But you can pass the image as a stream in other ways. If you will give more context about the image source and destination then I would be able to help you deal with that.

Comment: Ok, I update the question with my final purpose

Answer (score 2):

While I guess that the best solution would be to retrieve the image as a stream and then pipe it, you can also try the library `into-stream` by Sindre Sorhus https://github.com/sindresorhus/into-stream, that will convert your string (the base64 representation of the image) into a stream, already chunked

EDIT

now that you wrote the code, you can simply convert the string to a stream and use it as argument for write with that library. You could do it without the library simply creating a readable stream that chunks the dataurl correctly and yields the chunks one by one

Answer (score 0):

Finally i decided to use the library `into-stream`as @grokked suggested, in order to convert directly the retrieved image to a stream. Then i can use the stream after to store the image by the MongoDB GridFS system. Thank you all for your answers :)

```
    import * as intoStream from 'into-stream';





    const image = req.body.myImage;

    const imageString = intoStream(image);

    .......

    imageString.myCustomSaveFunction(...)
```